# Is there a way to overlay a bar chart (matplotlib) onto a map (geopandas)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I plot the map like this. How can I overlay it with a barplot?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
ax = world.plot()
plt.show()
```

It should be similar to this image I found online:

[image: Example Image]

Comment: I think that it's possible, but I don't understand how do you expect the plots are overlaid. Can you provide a visual example?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I edited my question and provided an example image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to overlay the two plots, what is hard is to put the bar chart exactly over a point coordinate. I made this example with only one bar chart, but it's only an approximation:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
fig = plt.figure()
ax_map = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
world.plot(ax=ax_map)
lat, lon = 19.432608, -99.133208
ax_bar = fig.add_axes([0.5*(1+lon/180) , 0.5*(1+lat/90) , 0.05, 0.05])
ax_bar.bar([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], color=['C1', 'C2', 'C3'])
ax_bar.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: My answer using `inset_axes` can position the bar charts more precisely, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55854988/subplots-onto-a-basemap/55890475#55890475 . Hope it is useful for the readers who seek alternate solution.

Comment: Why is it difficult to put the bar chart exactly over a point coordinate? Shouldn't the same formula work for all points?