# Proportional coloring of Polygons in python 3.8

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas, colormap

Example: Display the percentage of cars driving in a country. In my case blue (40%), red (40%) and green (20%) cars. The country is a given polygon which might look like the left one. I want to color each country by a given variable which would look like the right one in the given example.

[image]

Code for the example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from geopandas import GeoSeries
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p1 = Polygon([(2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 1), (2, 1)])
p2 = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)])
green = GeoSeries(Polygon([(2, 0), (3, 0), (3, 0.2), (2, 0.2)]))
red = GeoSeries(Polygon([(2, 0.6), (3, 0.6), (3, 0.2), (2, 0.2)]))
blue = GeoSeries(Polygon([(2, 0.6), (3, 0.6), (3, 1), (2, 1)]))

g = GeoSeries([p1, p2])

f , ax = plt.subplots(1)

g.boundary.plot(ax = ax, color = 'black')
green.plot(ax = ax, color = 'green')
red.plot(ax = ax, color = 'red')
blue.plot(ax = ax, color = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

I know how to make a color map for a set of polyogns but then every polygon does only have one color. Is there a way to make a colormap for each polygon depending on the percentage a certain variable takes into account for each polygon? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I find this answer to be very helpful.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854228/is-there-a-way-to-overlay-a-bar-chart-matplotlib-onto-a-map-geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854228/is-there-a-way-to-overlay-a-bar-chart-matplotlib-onto-a-map-geopandas)

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks for the link but i would love to have a soloution where the country itsel is colored.

Comment: If a country's shape is not nearly rectangle, how do you divide its area into desired percentage portions? If a country is proportionally very small on the map, how do you show such symbol for it?

Comment: One can calculate the area of a polygon. Therefore maybe split one country into polygons where each "split" represents the correct proportion, which then can be colored. This figure is more for illustrative purposes where one can zoom in and show specifics of the data, give an overview or examples. In presentations colored objects might be better than pure numbers. But in this case that might not be worse the expense.